# PHP Array - Missing Entry

Tags: php, arrays

Can anyone tell me, if there is an error in the following code, please?

```
eval ("\$typeselectbit = \"".$cmstpl->get("admin_selectbitdefault")."\";");
$result = $cmsdb->query("SELECT * FROM cms".$n."_type WHERE deleted = '0' ORDER BY typename ASC");
while ($type = $cmsdb->fetch_array($result))
{
    $typeid = $type['typeid'];
    $typename = $type['typename'];

    eval("\$typeselectbit .= \"".$cmstpl->get(ifelse($GPC['typeid'] == $typeid, "typeselectbit2", "typeselectbit"))."\";");
}
```

It doesn't output the first entry from the array. But maybe the error is somewhere else.

At the moment, I'm not sure, where this problem is coming from.

What do you think? Does it look correct to you?

And if not, what do I have to fix and how exactly should it look like?

Or do I have to look somewhere else in the script?

Any specific hints, which could help to find the reason?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Why are you using eval?

Comment: @Jenson But what is `eval` for? o_O

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your code `eval("\$typeselectbit .= \"".$cmstpl->get(ifelse($GPC['typeid'] == $typeid, "typeselectbit2", "typeselectbit"))."\";");` has a parse error. `ifelse` is not valid PHP syntax (*unless that is a function you have declared previously*). It could also be any other number of errors occurring inside of the `eval` construct.

[According to the manual](http://php.net/eval)

> If there is a parse error in the evaluated code, `eval()` returns `FALSE` and execution of the following code continues normally. It is not possible to catch a parse error in `eval()` using [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/set-error-handler).

It's not clear why you chose to use `eval` at all here, but one of the down sides, among others, is that you typically can't easily debug these kinds of errors inside of `eval`. If you ran this code outside of `eval` you'd immediately see the parse error.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can see, "ifelse" is the following function: function ifelse ($expression,$returntrue,$returnfalse="")
{
 if (!$expression)
 {
  return $returnfalse;
 }
 else
 {
  return $returntrue;
 }
}

Comment: So check the return values of your `eval` code and if it returns `false` then you still have some other error in there. You'll need to debug it outside of eval if it's a parse error or tail your error logs for other errors or just turn on display errors. Like I said, errors inside of `eval` are not always obvious and definitely not pleasant to debug.